# Dockerfile set ENV based on npm package version

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a line in a dockerfile to set the container's environment variable based on the output of an `npm` script:

```
ENV BUILD_VERSION=$(npm pkg get version | sed 's/"//g')
```

running `npm pkg get version | sed 's/"//g'` in my terminal outputs:

```
❯ npm pkg get version | sed 's/"//g' 
4.12.3
```

But, in the dockerfile I get this error when building:

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: Syntax error - can't find = in "pkg". Must be of the form: name=value

Comment: `ENV` doesn't support interpolating command output as far as I know. This can be solved using a build argument, though. So where ever you are running `docker build` you can include the `--build-arg` option and interpolate your build version into that, instead.

Comment: Examples [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

Comment: Thanks @ant i was hoping to have this automated in the dockerfile as opposed to having to enter yet another build command (if possible!)